# how to solve this error (Assigning to 'id<InputStream>' from incompatible type 'NSStream *')?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am doing upgrade code of mac plugin. I found one method but i could not understand this error. Code is here. its define in `.h` file.

```
id<OutputStream> _sendStream;
```

and method is in `.m` file.

```
- (void)setSendStream:(NSStream *)stream {
    if (stream != _sendStream) {
        [_sendStream autorelease];
        _sendStream = [stream retain];
    }
}
```

This method give error

> Assigning to '`id<InputStream>`' from incompatible type '`NSStream *`'

How to solve this error because i am new in mac development. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)setSendStream:(id<OutputStream>)stream {
   //...
}
```

Comment: But this method also give Conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'setSendStream:': 'id<OutputStream> *' vs 'id<OutputStream>'. How to solve this?

Comment: Yes, I was half asleep - the * shouldn't be there. See my revised answer.

Comment: @AmitGujjar How'bout making some research effort yourself too, even if an incorrect answer is posted, by the way...

Comment: Thanks for suggestion H2CO3. I am searching this error before 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

An `NSStream` object does not conform to the `OutputStream` protocol. Your method should look like this:

```
- (void)setSendStream:(id <OutputStream>)stream
{ 
  if (stream != _sendStream) {
    [_sendStream autorelease];
    _sendStream = [stream retain];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marcel. But this method also give  Conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'setSendStream:': 'id<OutputStream> *' vs 'id<OutputStream>'. How to solve this?

Comment: you should not use the pointer '*' with `id`. When I test this, the compiler does not complain.

Comment: Thanks Marcel.Its fine now.